# Calculate bootstrapped confidence intervals for c-statistics in a logistic regression using DescTools::Cstat

Tags: r, logistic, confidence-interval, bootstrap

A reviewer requested that we provide uncertainty measure of our c-statistics, and I guess 95% confidence interval is a good answer. I checked the manual of `DescTools::Cstat()`, and it says:

> Confidence intervals for this measure can be calculated by bootstrap.

However, I can't find any example of calculating bootstrapped CI for c-statistics online. Can anybody provide an example of doing that in R. Here is a replicable example of conducting logistic regression in R:

```
d = mtcars
d$y = ifelse(mtcars$mpg >= 20, 1, 0)
fit = glm(y ~ gear + carb, data = d, family = "binomial")
DescTools::Cstat(fit)
# [1] 0.9430894
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package `boot`. You need to create a function that takes in a dataset, subset it according to the index, and then calculates an output.

For you situation, I created a function call `func`

```
func = function(Data,ind){
  fit = glm(y ~ gear + carb, data = Data[ind,], family = "binomial")
  DescTools::Cstat(fit)
}
```

The first argument is Data, which is your input data frame. The 2nd is the indices from which the `boot` function will sample for you. You can see inside the glm function, I subset Data based on ind.

So now the bootstrap:

```
library(boot)
res = boot(d,func,R=999)
```

Some of them will throw errors because it did not converge.. I hope for yours it doesn't. You can look at the ci using boot.ci, here i chose percentile, but there are other methods:

```
boot.ci(res,type="perc")
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 999 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = res, type = "perc")

Intervals : 
Level     Percentile     
95%   ( 0.8852,  1.0000 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: you're welcome :) All the best with the reviews !